# Best Eve-online Starter Character for research alt

Tags: eve-online

I want to use one of my character slots to research BPOs at my Hi-Sec POS, and would therefore like to limit the amount of time I have to spend training them.

So, what is the best Race/Blood-line/Education combination to give the best set of Science/Research-oriented skills?

I have found some articles/blogs from circa-2007 to 2010, but these don't seem to apply any more since the release of Incarna.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting skills make a difference of a few hours at maximum, nothing you really need to worry about. And I checked some characters of mine and it seems you don't get any skill difference in the science skills in any case. You get Science 3, and that's it.

I also would not worry about the attributes, as you have a specific skill plan you should remap them immediately anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to recall from a few years ago that a specific combination on race/bloodline/profession gave science V, etc, which was perfect for an almost no-training research alt. Is that no longer possible? (I'd rather not stop the training of my main)

Comment: @Crollster A while ago CCP changed the setup for new characters. They don't get as many starting skills or SP, and the race/bloodline/profession combinations don't really do much anymore. Rolling up a new character is not supposed to supremely impact new players, because how would they know what they really want to do in the end? Roll an alt, re-spec to int/mem (or mem/int, can't remember which), train one level of Cybernetics for the +3s, train skills.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable enough, i guess.